# ML kit model downloading show on Application

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

i have try [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/translate-text#manage_models) code  for download ML kit model . it show on notification bar  but i want to show using [progressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) so user know how many percentage model file downloaded because this file take too much time to download

Comment: did you find anything?